# Getting HP ThinPro T5325 to PXE Boot

Tags: pxe

I have a HP ThinPro T5325 from the ebays.  It is a neat little device that I bought with the intention to boot from the network.  I have successfully booted other devices and a few VMs via PXE and my Debian host, with heaping piles of success.  However, I started working on the ThinPro once it came in, and I seem to be hitting a wall.

I can not seem to get the device to PXE boot.  It get's an IP address, and boots to the ThinPro OS fine.  I also have HP Device Manager running, and the two are connected.  However, despite all of this work, and some digging in the software, I can not find anywhere to trigger/configure a PXE boot, or (in desperation) remove the image and hopefully force a PXE boot.

If this were a PC, I would enter the BIOS and change the boot order...  But I can not find any documentation on entering the ThinPro bios...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the following specs:
http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01951378

The T5325 is an ARM-based computer. It doesn't have a BIOS like you'd find on x86 machines.

It means that this computer doesn't support PXE boot. You have to get a firmware / OS installed on the local storage if you want it to boot.

Comment: I did learn that. I made something work for now. Generally pleased. Thank you.